# How to solve the target tag remove issue in JSOUP doing crawler

Tags: java, jquery, jsoup

I want to ask the question: HOW TO REMOVE THE SELECTED TAG

website is www.yellowbook.com

My Code is

```
for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    String shopNameTemp = "";
    String shopAddressTempA = "";
    String shopAddressTempB = "";
    String shopAddressTempC = "";
    String shopAddressTempD = "";
    String shopTelTemp = "";
    String divName = "divInAreaSummary_" + String.valueOf(i);

    Elements node = doc.select("li[id=" + divName);

    shopNameTemp = node.first().select("a[class=fn]").toString();
    shopAddressTempA = node.first().select("span[class=street-address]").toString();
    shopAddressTempB = node.first().select("span[class=locality]").toString();
    shopAddressTempC = node.first().select("span[class=region]").toString();
    shopAddressTempD = node.first().select("span[class=postal-code]").toString();
    shopTelTemp = node.first().select("div[class=call phone-number]").toString();
    System.out.println("Name  " + shopNameTemp);
    System.out.println("Address" + shopAddressTempA + shopAddressTempB + shopAddressTempC + shopAddressTempD);
    System.out.println("Tel   " + shopTelTemp);

}
```

My Output is:

```
Please input your category and location and Province...

auto repair,Seattle,WA


Name <#a class="fn" data-classid="690" href="/profile/76-station-mlk_1861635669.html" onclick="OmAdViewLeadClick('adsource: companyname', false, '8330', ';7;;;;evar33=inArea|evar34=16', 'auto repairing');" title="View more information about 76 Station MLK">76 Station MLK<#/a>

Address   <#span itemprop="streetAddress" class="street-address">15 Avenue Nw<#/span><#span itemprop="addressLocality" class="locality">Seattle<#/span><#span itemprop="addressRegion" class="region">WA<#/span><#span itemprop="postalCode" class="postal-code">98102-9810<#/span>
Tel   <#div class="call phone-number">
(206) 826-3263
<#/div>
```

How can I only get

> Name   76 Station MLK
>
> Address 15 Avenue Nw Seattle WA 98102-9810
>
> Tel (206) 826-3263

PS. I use remove, the content will be removed, but tag still exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `toString()`, use the `text()` method of Element to extract only the text and no tags.

For example:

```
shopNameTemp = node.first().select("a[class=fn]").text();
shopAddressTempA = node.first().select("span[class=street-address]").text();
shopAddressTempB = node.first().select("span[class=locality]").text();
shopAddressTempC = node.first().select("span[class=region]").text();
shopAddressTempD = node.first().select("span[class=postal-code]").text();
shopTelTemp = node.first().select("div[class=call phone-number]").text();
```

That should result in the correct text when you print it to console. Note that you may have to manually add some spaces (e.g. `+ " " +`) between `shopAddressTempA`, `shopAddressTempB` etc, otherwise all of those will print with no spaces.

I tested this and my output is:

```
Name  76 Station MLK
Address 2801 Martin Luther King Jr Way S Seattle WA 98144-6003
Tel   (206) 722-4995
```